# How to remove AST nodes with pycparser?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, pycparser

Let's start by considering this snippet:

```
import sys

from pycparser import c_parser, c_ast, c_generator


text = r"""
void main() {
    foo(1,3);

    foo1(4);

    x = 1;

     foo2(4,

        10,


        3);
    foo3(
        "xxx"

    );
}
"""


class FuncCallVisitor(c_ast.NodeVisitor):

    def visit_FuncCall(self, node):
        print('%s called at %s' % (node.name.name, node.name.coord))

        if node.args:
            self.visit(node.args)


class RemoveFuncCalls(c_generator.CGenerator):

    def visit_FuncCall(self, n):
        # fref = self._parenthesize_unless_simple(n.name)
        # return fref + '(' + self.visit(n.args) + ')'
        return ""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = c_parser.CParser()
    ast = parser.parse(text)
    v = FuncCallVisitor()
    v.visit(ast)
    print('-' * 80)

    ast.show(showcoord=True)
    generator = RemoveFuncCalls()

    print('-' * 80)
    print(generator.visit(ast))
```

The output of the above will be:

```
void main()
{
  ;
  ;
  x = 1;
  ;
  ;
}
```

But I'd like it to become this instead:

```
void main()
{
  x = 1;
}
```

So my question is, what's the canonical/idiomatic way to delete nodes/subtrees from the AST with pycparser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `c_generator.CGenerator` calls [`_generate_stmt` method](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/blob/master/pycparser/c_generator.py#L334) for scope-like structures [which appends `';\n'`](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/blob/master/pycparser/c_generator.py#L352) (with indentation) to result of `visit` for statement even if it is an empty string.

To remove function calls we can overload it like

```py
class RemoveFuncCalls(c_generator.CGenerator):
    def _generate_stmt(self, n, add_indent=False):
        if isinstance(n, c_ast.FuncCall):
            return ''
        else:
            return super()._generate_stmt(n, add_indent)
```

with that

```py
void main()
{
  x = 1;
}
```

which looks like what you want.

Let's consider a case

```c
if (bar(42, "something"))
    return;
```

if we need it to become

```c
if ()
    return;
```

then we need to add

```py
    def visit_FuncCall(self, n):
        return ''
```

like in OP, because `_generate_stmt` isn't called by `RemoveFuncCalls.visit_If` method for `cond` field serialization.

## Going further

I don't know what "canonical/idiomatic way to delete nodes/subtrees from the AST with pycparser", but I do know one for `ast` module from stdlib -- [`ast.NodeTransformer` class](https://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer) (which is absent in `pycparser` for some reason).

It will allow us to avoid messing with how AST is serialized to `str` by overriding private'ish methods and modify AST itself

```py
from pycparser import c_ast

class NodeTransformer(c_ast.NodeVisitor):
    def generic_visit(self, node):
        for field, old_value in iter_fields(node):
            if isinstance(old_value, list):
                new_values = []
                for value in old_value:
                    if isinstance(value, c_ast.Node):
                        value = self.visit(value)
                        if value is None:
                            continue
                        elif not isinstance(value, c_ast.Node):
                            new_values.extend(value)
                            continue
                    new_values.append(value)
                old_value[:] = new_values
            elif isinstance(old_value, c_ast.Node):
                new_node = self.visit(old_value)
                setattr(node, field, new_node)
        return node


def iter_fields(node):
    # this doesn't look pretty because `pycparser` decided to have structure 
    # for AST node classes different from stdlib ones
    index = 0
    children = node.children()
    while index < len(children):
        name, child = children[index]
        try:
            bracket_index = name.index('[')
        except ValueError:
            yield name, child
            index += 1
        else:
            name = name[:bracket_index]
            child = getattr(node, name)
            index += len(child)
            yield name, child
```

and for our case it can be simply subclassed

```py
class FuncCallsRemover(NodeTransformer):
    def visit_FuncCall(self, node):
        return None
```

and used like

```py
...
ast = parser.parse(text)
v = FuncCallsRemover()
ast = v.visit(ast)  # note that `NodeTransformer` returns modified AST instead of `None`
```

after that we can use unmodified `c_generator.CGenerator` instance and get the same result.